# Can't make vertical fly out sub-menu go full screen

Tags: css

I am using a standard css vertical navigation menu that uses ":hover" to show the sub menu. The menu is done using standard "ul" and "li" elements. The menu is on the left hand side of the page, and when you hover over a menu, it pops out the sub menu to the right of it.

My question is, the sub menu that pops out, is there a way to make it full screen height?

### UPDATE

here is a very easy sample:
http://jsfiddle.net/NuAWQ/1/

All the surrounding html/css has been removed so that all you can see is the menu.

### UPDATE

I have now managed to do this by using jQuery. The jQuery is:

`$('ul > li > ul').css('height', $(window).height() + 'px');`

http://jsfiddle.net/NuAWQ/2/

Comment: We can't really give you a good answer unless you share your code.

Comment: fair enough, I have updated the question

Comment: In your fiddle, there isn't enough extra markup for the menu to extend into. Try going onto your regular page and add `height:100%` into `#menuwrapper ul li ul`

Comment: I already tried this on my main markup, and also the fiddle markup, with no change.

Comment: `height: 100%` won't work because that's the 100% height of the parent element. So unless the parent `li` is 100% tall too, it won't work.

Comment: I managed to get it to work with javascript - "$('ul > li > ul').css('height', $(window).height() + 'px');"

Comment: @eyeballpaul -- do you still want to line up your submenus with the parent hovered menu item?

Comment: Cheers @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas I see your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This gave the intended result.

$('ul > li > ul').css('height', $(window).height() + 'px');

However, also see Roddy's additional answer if you wish to align the child elements with the parent element.

Answer (score 1):

Just some extra information if anyone was curious.

In addition to the solution from above, that fixes the whole sizing issue using jQuery: `$('ul > li > ul').css('height', $(window).height() + 'px');` ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/NuAWQ/2/)), it is possible to further align the child menu items with the hovered parent item by extending the jQuery code.

[JSFiddle demo is here](http://jsfiddle.net/wSN2W/2/). The following jQuery code was added to the above that was already mentioned:

```
$('ul > li > ul > li:first-child').css('margin-top', function(index, value) {
    var offset = $(this).parent().parent().offset();

    if (offset != null && offset.top > 0) {
        return offset.top + "px";
    } else {
        return 0 + "px";
    }
});
```

Pretty much what this does is it takes every submenu and adds a `margin-top` to the first `<li>` that is the same as the vertical offset of the hovered parent menu item. In the above demo, this only works on the first submenu, but I'm pretty sure that it could be applied to all submenus with a tweak to the CSS selector or the offset-getting logic.